# How to implement Login Dialog in JavaFX using ControlsFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I tried to use custom dialog from http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialog.html, but the code is not working throwing this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/scene/traversal/ParentTraversalEngine
at org.controlsfx.control.ButtonBar.<init>(ButtonBar.java:414)
at org.controlsfx.control.ButtonBar.<init>(ButtonBar.java:357)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.createButtonPanel(Dialog.java:1034)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.createCenterPanel(Dialog.java:1029)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.buildDialogContent(Dialog.java:950)
at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:320)
....
```

The other thing is there is no example of how to integrate this to be used in a real world application, as of where do you put this code to authenticate user then continue loading your application, and maybe how to use this code to authenticate in the middle of an action, thus needs to be more re-usable.

I am using Java 8.0u20 and ControlsFX 8.0.6_20 from maven

Comment: Are you sure you're using Java 8u20? This is a known error if running ControlsFX 8.0.6_20 with 8u11

Comment: I look it up in the Java Control Panel and it says that the version is Java 8 Update 20 (build 1.8.0_20-b26)

Comment: Can you just add the line System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
 to be sure (there might be multiple versions installed on your machine, eclipse / your IDE might be pointing at a different one...

Comment: uh oh you're right. It prints out `1.8.0_05`

Comment: Thanks @Adam, while figuring out how to update it, how about the second question?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Java version, most likely you're running with an older version than 8u20.

You can add this line to your app to check at runtime which JRE is being used.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Comment: I'll look at it later, sorry busy at mo.